# Support mobile phones, phablets but not tablets

Tags: android, google-play, screen, android-manifest, sim-card

I would like my application to support mobiles and phablets only not the tablets. I have used the following cod ein my manifest file to support mobile phones and phablets.

```
 <compatible-screens>

    <!-- all small size screens -->
    <screen
        android:screenDensity="ldpi"
        android:screenSize="small" />
    <screen
        android:screenDensity="mdpi"
        android:screenSize="small" />
    <screen
        android:screenDensity="hdpi"
        android:screenSize="small" />
    <screen
        android:screenDensity="xhdpi"
        android:screenSize="small" />
    <!-- all normal size screens -->
    <screen
        android:screenDensity="ldpi"
        android:screenSize="normal" />
    <screen
        android:screenDensity="mdpi"
        android:screenSize="normal" />
    <screen
        android:screenDensity="hdpi"
        android:screenSize="normal" />
    <screen
        android:screenDensity="xhdpi"
        android:screenSize="normal" />
</compatible-screens>
```

I am not sure if the above code will support phablets or not. Is this correct ?

**Edit**

Basically I just want to support devices which supports sim card. Is there any other way to find out ?

Comment: even some of the tablets support sim card..

Comment: @basant_matharu Yeah I know but its okay. My main aim is for mobile phones and phablets for now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify in your manifest that you wish only to support devices with **Telephony** feature's available. As mentioned in the comment on question, it is not a fool proof technique to eliminate all the tablets.

```
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.telephony" android:required="true" />
```

Comment: I can confirm that by using this feature (and excluding the compatible screens), your app will be available for tablets with a sim card.